# Why MapView.Marker does not exist on type 'typeof MapView'?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm developing an android application "Location Finder" in react native and for that I installed "react-native-maps" package. It is showing the map and location properly but now I need to place the pointer on location for that I used "" but it says "Marker does not exist on type 'typeof MapView'"

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

I have followed the above URL to install and implement the functionality.

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

```
<MapView style={styles.map} region={props.userLocation}>
     <MapView.Marker />
</MapView>
```

"Marker" should be available as I have imported "MapView" from "react-native-maps".
But it is giving me the following error.
"Property 'Marker' does not exist on type 'typeof MapView'.ts"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you try this? You can import `Marker`

```js
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
<MapView style={styles.map} region={props.userLocation}>
     <Marker />
</MapView>
```